# Convert CGcolorRef to UIColor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I was wondering how can convert `CGcolorRef` to `UIColor` ? I have created a custom method for my own and I need it to use UIColor

EDITED method :

```
    - (void)fontColor:(CGColorRef)colors setString(NSSTring *)blah blah blah  {

    coreTextLayer.foregroundColor = color;


    }


[myClass fontColor:[UIColor redColor] setString....];
```

the right way is use something like this :

```
[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
```

but is there any way to use only UIColor?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Does `+ (UIColor *)colorWithCGColor:(CGColorRef)cgColor` not do what you need?

---

Follow-up:

Try implementing your method as something like:

```
- (void)setFontColor:(UIColor *)color forString(NSString *)aString  {
    [coreTextLayer setForegroundColor:[color CGColor]];
    ...
}
```

(Adjusted to be more in line with Cocoa naming conventions, and to not use dot syntax. ;-)

Comment: ammm Actually it's not only UIColor my method is something like this :
   `- (void)fontColor:(CGColorRef)colors setString(NSSTring *)blah blah blah {`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish here.  What I wrote *does* return an UIColor given a CGColorRef.  What is your concern?

Comment: Though your updated code makes it seem that you want to go in the opposite direction, i.e., `[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]`.

Comment: Yes , i use it like this but is there any possible way to use only UIColor ?

Comment: See my updated answer, with CGColor relegated to being an internal implementation detail.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use

> - (UIColor *)initWithCGColor:(CGColorRef)cgColor