# How to add a color to each line segment?

Tags: ios, swift

How would I add a color to each line? I want all the lines to have a different color. For example, one side blue another red another green.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    shape = CAShapeLayer()
    view.layer.addSublayer(shape)
    shape.opacity = 0.5
    shape.lineWidth = 2
    shape.lineJoin = kCALineJoinMiter
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor(hue: 0.786, saturation: 0.79, brightness: 0.53, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    shape.fillColor = UIColor(hue: 0, saturation: 0, brightness: 0, alpha: 0).CGColor

    path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(150, 300))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(230, 300))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(250, 350))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(230, 400))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(150, 400))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(150, 400))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(130, 350))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(150, 300))
    path.closePath()
    shape.path = path.CGPath
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single path (single shape layer) is drawn in a single color. You should probably create a separate shape layer for each desired color and put the line segments you want to be drawn in the same color into each shape layer's path (using moveToPoint/lineToPoint to create discontinuous lines).

Add all your shape layers as sublayers to the view that you want to contain your drawing.

Comment: How would I convert CGColor to UIColor? I want to use the generic UIColors.

Comment: You can see the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10050086/2174668 (CGColor to UIColor).

Comment: Why do you need to convert `CGColor` to a `UIColor`? Usually when dealing with layers you have to go the other way. (You want to specify `UIColors` but `CALayers` use `CGColors` so you have to convert from `UIColor` to `CGColor`).